# Apache camel: Multiple executions with onCompletion mode="BeforeConsumer"

Tags: apache-camel

Sorry for my english, I'll make my best effort for write this.

I have a xml file like this:

```
<routes>
    <route id="id1">
        <from uri="timer://foo?fixedRate=true&amp;period=60s"/>
        <onCompletion mode="BeforeConsumer">
            <log message="finish"/>
        </onCompletion>
        <setBody>
            <simple>Probando 1</simple>
        </setBody>
       <log message="working1"/>
        <to uri="direct:test1"/>
    </route>
    <route id="id2">
        <from uri="direct:test1"/>
        <setBody>
            <simple>Test2</simple>
        </setBody>
        <log message="working2"/>
        <to uri="direct:test2"/>
    </route>
    <route id="id3">
        <from uri="direct:test2"/>
        <setBody>
            <simple>Test3</simple>
        </setBody>
        <log message="working3"/>
   </route>
</routes>
```

if remove mode="BeforeConsumer" from the first route i get one "finish" in the log, but if i use the xml with mode="BeforeConsumer" i get the message 3 times (one per each route). Is that the behavior expected?

I need that the onCompletion code runs one time but i need too the mode="BeforeConsumer"

Comment: Weird. This looks like a camel bug, I can't imagine this is working as intended. As a workaround you can move `onCompletion` below the line `<to uri="direct:test1"/>`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have a lot of workarounds, but i was trying to know if i was doing something wrong. I think that i'll try to open a ticket on the camel bug tracker